# Creating value in QGIS based on multiple "OR"-conditions

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table

Different cities are part of the same subregional group. I would like to assign this same name to all these cities. I want to live the other cells empty. So far I have tried these but it doesn't work:

```
CASE
   WHEN "l_co" = 'Romainville' OR 'Bagnolet' OR 'Bobigny' OR 'Bondy' OR 'Les Lilas' OR 'Montreuil' OR 'Noisy-le-Sec' OR 'Le Pré-Saint-Gervais' OR 'Pantin'
   THEN "EPCI" = 'Est Ensemble'
   ELSE ''
END

CASE
   WHEN "l_co" in ('Romainville','Bagnolet' ,'Bobigny','Bondy' ,'Les Lilas','Montreuil','Noisy-le-Sec' ,'Le Pré-Saint-Gervais','Pantin')
   THEN "EPCI" = 'Est Ensemble'
   ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to write something into the EPCI column? Then remove the `"EPCI" = ` part from the bottom code, and add the `''` after the ELSE.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're already "telling" the field calculator which column to edit/create, there's no need to do so again in the expression itself.

Comment: Yes I need to get used to this, I am really a beginner (learned ArcGIS a long time ago but not at a very advanced level). I will try to find some tutorials online as well.

Comment: Just a quick question: when i want to do this for another group of cities (assigning them with another name) it erases the first group, I think it is because of the ELSE ' '. Is there a way to avoid this? This assumes I don't know or don't want to add all the names of the groups of cities in one go.

Comment: i tried but even without else it seems to erase my previous entries. For instance if I have other cities that are in the "Plaine Commune group", it erases all the cells written "Est Ensemble" for the other cities.

Answer (score 2):

The answer (courtesy of @Erik):

```
CASE
   WHEN "l_co" in ('Romainville','Bagnolet' ,'Bobigny','Bondy' ,'Les Lilas','Montreuil','Noisy-le-Sec' ,'Le Pré-Saint-Gervais','Pantin')
   THEN 'Est Ensemble'
   ELSE ''
END
```